# Space of meromorphic functions is not finitely generated

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-spaces, riemann-surfaces, meromorphic-functions

During a lesson of the course on Riemann Surfaces our lecturer made the following remark, saying this could be proved as an exercise:

The space $\mathcal{M}(X)$ of meromorphic functions on a compact Riemann surface, if not empty, is not finite dimensional (as a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$).

This is a bit confusing: this was stated before Riemann-Roch, whence the "if not empty". Anyway, holomorphic functions are always also meromorhic, so this is in any case a problem. Besides, the space of meromorphic functions which are not holomorphic is not a vector space, so what is meant here?  I have adjusted the statement as follows (still in a "pre-Riemann-Roch" setting):

Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface. If there exists a function $f \in \mathcal{M}(X)-\mathcal{O}(X)$, then $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is infinite dimensional. Does this hold true? How can this be proved (without Riemann-Roch)?

I have tought to go by induction on number of generators. I am able to prove directly that it cannot be generated by two elements: suppose these two elements are called $g$ and $h$, one of the two, say $g$, is a constant, then if $f$ (the same as above) has a pole of order $n$ at a point $p$, also $h$ must have a pole of order $n$ at $p$, now also $h^2$ is meromorphic but cannot be written as a linear combination of $g$ and $h$, since $\mathrm{ord}_p h^2 = 2n$.

Now I'd like to prove that if $\mathcal{M}(X)$ is generated by $n$ functions, it is also generated by $n-1$ functions; but how?

Alternatively: every "polynomial in $f$", that is any expression of the form $a_0+ a_1 f + \ldots + a_n f^n$, where powers are respect to point-wise multiplication, is again in $\mathcal{M}(X)$, if this map $\mathbb{C}[z] \to \mathcal{M}(X)$ is injective, we are done. But is it?

Comment: On a compact Riemann surface, all holomorphic functions are constant. Conversely, all constant functions are holomorphic, and *a fortiori* meromorphic. But it's a deep theorem that there is a non-constant meromorphic function on each compact Riemann surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have a meromorphic function $f$ on a compact Riemann surface, that is not constant, then $f$ will have a pole; of order $m$ at a point $P$. Then the $f^n$
are linearly independent over $\Bbb C$ since $f^n$ has a pole of order $mn$ at $P$,
and functions with poles of different orders at $P$ are linearly independent.

Comment: How do you prove this? Just with Laurent expansions? This would also mean that my map $\mathbb{C}[z]\to\mathcal{M}(X)$ is injective.

Comment: Laurent expansions in a neighbourhood of $P$ work fine here.

Answer (score 0):

A meromorphic function $f$ on a Riemann surface $X$ satisfying a non-trivial polynomial equation $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i f^i=0$ with complex coefficients $a_i\in\mathbb C$ is locally constant: We have that $0=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i f^i=a_n\prod_{i=1}^n(f-\lambda_i)$ for suitable $\lambda_i\in \mathbb C$ and so for every $x\in X$ which is not a pole of $f$, $f(x)$ equals one of the $\lambda_i$. Thus, $f$ is locally constant everywhere where it is defined. Hence, $f$ is homomorphic and locally constant.

Comment: You wrote 'equation', but there's no equation here...

Comment: You're right, thanks, fixed.